# AWS lambda unable to create a scheduled event source

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Unable to create a recurring schedule for lambda.

What I did:

1) Created the function and successfully tested it.

2) Went to event source section in the AWS mgmt console.

3) clicked on add event source.

4) with default settings of rate(5 minutes) clicked on submit.

Got the error:

> There was an error creating the event source mapping: Could not create
>   scheduled-event event source

I went through the docs and ran this statement via AWS CLI:

```
aws lambda add-permission --statement-id Allow-scheduled-events --action lambda:InvokeFunction --principal events.amazonaws.com --function-name function:myfunction
```

The above statement went through successfully, I tried running it again and it said the permission already exists confirming that it ran.

I tried adding the schedule again but got the same error.

Am i supposed to change the role or something? Can't anything else in the docs. The lambda is running with basic lambda execution role.

**UPDATE**

I temporarily gave the role under which the Lambda is executing admin access, still the same error.

**Workaround**

FYI... for people facing this problem, I could achieve the same result by going to cloudwatch and adding an event targeting lambda from there... same thing, that still does not answer this question though. I cant imagine that AWS console has such a gaping bug that they aren't doing anything about.

Comment: FYI... for people facing this problem, I could achieve the same result by going to cloudwatch and adding an event targeting lambda from there... same thing, that still does not answer this question though. I cant imagine that AWS console has such a gaping bug that they aren't doing anything about.

Comment: Yeah, seems like no event sources can be created. Incredibly frustrating. Have you contacted AWS support?

Comment: Oh, nevermind! I thought you meant that doing it the other way didn't work either. Just tried it also and was able to get it working. Only annoying thing is you can't add CloudWatch events to $LATEST.

Comment: Yeah, I saw a post from support where they acknowledged the bug, it is surprising still

Comment: Just tried it again– looks like it's fixed! :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case my Lambda and S3 were not in the same region. I found out by, instead of adding the trigger on the Lambda, adding the event from s3.

Comment: yeah the reverse worked then as well, thanks for checking @dandoen